# Composer multiple projects?

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, flarum

I am trying composer on some projects and wondering... actually I have installed a CodeIgniter 4 by composer in my httpdocs/ folder.
Now I would like to install Flarum (forum) as well to have it referenced in my project (like domain.tld/forum links to flarum instance).
Questions is: How do I get both up and running in the same space? I don't want to use a subdomain for Flarum.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not simply install Flarum in a second folder besides the given application?

Comment: I tried to install Flarum in the public folder... which is not a good idea after all as then the code base is in the web accessible space and has another public folder (like ./public/flarum_dir/public/ ). Putting the Flarum in the root of CI doesn't work either nor putting both composer.json in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot combine these projects into one composer project. Even if the dependencies wouldn't clash, they will at some point.

In your comments you mention installing flarum in a subfolder of the public_html, this is the best course of action. There's no need to be afraid of critical files becoming web accessible if you follow the path customizing instructions in the Flarum documentation: https://docs.flarum.org/install#customizing-paths

Disclaimer, I'm part of the Flarum team.